# Questions on the mathoverflow newsletter

Tags: discussion, newsletter

Good morning, everyone...

I have a little question about the **math***overflow* newsletter.

Ever since I subscribed to it, I used to find it every Tuesday in my gmail inbox, but I have not received the August 10th "issue" of it yet. Did any of you receive it already?

Thanks in advance for your attention!

Comment: There's a mathoverflow newsletter?

Comment: @GerryMyerson You can find some basic info [in the corresponding tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/newsletter/info).

Comment: @Martin, one of the links at that page returned a 404. 
 https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=mathoverflow.net

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have noticed that - and that's the reason why I suggested an edit to change it [to this link](https://mathoverflow.net/digest/preview). The edit is currently [waiting for review](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/1652). (Although on MathOverflow Meta, approval of a suggested edit [can take quite a long time](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.mathoverflow/query/942650/longest-time-between-edit-suggestion-and-approval-only-tag-info?num=100).)

Comment: I can confirm that I received the email with the newsletter this week. (Mine comes on Thursdays.) At one point I had problems with e-mail from SE - but only with the inbox notifications, not the newsletter. It happened shortly after one of them was not delivered (because of Gmail outage). What helped back then was to change (temporarily) the e-mail address in my profile. More about this can be found in this post and the comments there: [Did the emails with notifications about inbox messages stop?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357939)